# How to add custom styles to npm module powerBi-report-component

Tags: reactjs, powerbi

I am using npm module powerbi-report-component in my react application. I need to change background color and colors of the text in the report.

```
const reportStyle = {
  width: '350px',
  height: '660px',
  color: 'red !important',
  border: '0',
  padding: '0px',
  background: '#33444C',
  bgColor: '#33444C',
};
```

I am sending this reportStyles to report module..but they are not applied to the component. Can anyone please help me with this.